# Create a group id over a window in Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a dataframe where I want to give id's in each Window partition. For example I have

```
id | col |
1  |  a  |
2  |  a  |
3  |  b  |
4  |  c  |
5  |  c  |
```

So I want (based on grouping with column col)

```
id | group |
1  |  1    |
2  |  1    |
3  |  2    |
4  |  3    |
5  |  3    |
```

I want to use a window function but I cannot find anyway to assign an Id to each window. I need something like:

```
w = Window().partitionBy('col')
df = df.withColumn("group", id().over(w))
```

Is there any way to achive somethong like that. (I cannot simply use col as a group id because I am interested in creating a window over multiple columns)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply using a `dense_rank` *inbuilt function over Window function* should give you your desired result as

```
from pyspark.sql import window as W
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.select('id', f.dense_rank().over(W.Window.orderBy('col')).alias('group')).show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+---+-----+
|id |group|
+---+-----+
|1  |1    |
|2  |1    |
|3  |2    |
|4  |3    |
|5  |3    |
+---+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I needed

Comment: this works but does not scale on large data. doing a global rank like this will cause spark to shuffle all of the data to a single executor to perform the rank.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a `row_number` for distinct `col` and self `join` with the original dataframe.

```
val data = Seq(
  (1, "a"),
  (2, "a"),
  (3, "b"),
  (4, "c"),
  (5, "c")
).toDF("id","col")

val df2 = data.select("col").distinct()
  .withColumn("group", row_number().over(Window.orderBy("col")))


val result = data.join(df2, Seq("col"), "left")
    .drop("col")
```

The code is in `scala` but can be easily changed to `pyspark`.

Hope this helps

Comment: I think this works for my case I will test it soon and close the question If it fits my problem

Answer (score 0):

Based on @koiralo I compiled this answer, which allows grouping for multiple columns and deciding if they should be dropped or not.
I used F.monotonically_increasing_id() to avoid OOM problems with the disadvantage that the numbers don't increase by 1, but should be rather considered random numbers.

```
from typing import List
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame

data = [[1, "a","la"], [2, "a","le"], [3, "b","la"],[4,"c","di"],[5,"c","di"]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema="id LONG, col STRING, other_col STRING")

def n_group(df:DataFrame, groupby: List[str], group_name:str = "group", drop_cols:bool = False)->DataFrame:
    groupby = [groupby] if isinstance(groupby, str) else groupby
    df_distinct = df.select(groupby).distinct()
    df_groups = df_distinct.withColumn(colName = group_name, col = F.monotonically_increasing_id())
    res = df.join(other=df_groups, on=groupby, how="left")
    if drop_cols: res = res.drop(*groupby)
    return res

n_group(df=df, groupby =["col"],group_name="group", drop_cols = False).show()
```