# add "group" column to a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, group-by

I need to add a new column in the followinf dataframe so that those that have the same value in column "column_1" must have the same numerical value, starting with 1 in a new column called "group"

````
``` # +---+-------------+
# | id| column_1|
# +---+-------------+
# |  0|    a    |
# |  7|    a    |
# |  1|    c    |
# |  2|    d    |
# |  3|    e    |
# |  4|    a    |
# | 10|    c    |
# | 12|    b    |
# +---+-------------+```
````

And I want:

````
``` # +---+-------------+
# | id| column_1| grupo|
# +---+-----------------+
# |  0|    a    |  1  | 
# |  7|    a    |  1  | 
# |  1|    c    |  3  | 
# |  2|    d    |  4  | 
# |  3|    e    |  5  | 
# |  4|    a    |  1  | 
# | 10|    c    |  3  | 
# | 12|    b    |  2  | 
# +---+-------------+```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a group id over a window in Spark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50233518/create-a-group-id-over-a-window-in-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

```py
windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("aux").orderBy("column_1")
df_expl = df_expl.withColumn("aux", F.lit(1))
df_expl = df_expl.withColumn("group",dense_rank().over(windowSpec))
df_expl = df_expl.drop("id")
```